# Finding Mean & Standard deviation of a normal distribution given probability of a range

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Is this possible?

Say we have a normal distribution of scores from range $~0 ~-~ 100~$, with $~(2/3)^{rd}~$ of score falling in between $~40 ~-~ 80~$.

Is the mean just $~50~$?

or do we calculate that somehow via $~Z~$ score given that:

We have $~P(40<X<80) = ($whatever the $~Z~$ value of $0.66$ is$)$.

I would have two equations to solve for mean & s.d. if there were two probabilities.

Feel like I am missing something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: When the distribution of the population is normal, then the distribution of the sample mean is also normal (http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/sampmn.htm) - Would this make is possible to infer the sd since 0 = 50 - 3*SD?

Comment: You cannot uniquely determine the mean from this information. You would need to have the standard deviation to find the mean, or have to mean to find the standard deviation.

Comment: However, one possible set of values is that the mean is $60$, and the standard deviation is $20.7$. This gives that $0.666048$ of students fall between $40$ to $80$ which is very close to $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Technically, no such thing as normal dist'n with support $[0,100].$ Ignoring that, @TobyMak's comment makes sense. I probably would have taken $2/3 \approx .68$ and used $\sigma = 20$ in accord with the 'Empirical Rule'.

Comment: Yes, the OP's question is ill-posed. You can take the integral of the standard deviation in the real numbers from $x=40$ to $80$, but it is not clear if that is what the OP wants.

Comment: Also, where did you get $50-3 SD$ from? Is there something more you need to add to the question so that it makes sense?